# Scraping and filling out a time-off request

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

In my ongoing quest to automate everything I have to do at my job, I've decided to learn how to do webscraping with VBA.  I wanted to start with something easy, so the following simply fills out a time-off request and submits it. My main goals while writing this were to:

1. Make the code readable and very obvious what everything does.
2. Try to keep everything as close to having one responsibility as possible.

You won't be able to really run this since I've had to redact some company information, but if you want to compile this, you'll need to enable references to Microsoft Internet Controls and Microsoft HTML Object Library.

With that out of the way, here's the main procedure:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Main()
    Dim model As FormModel
    Set model = New FormModel
    
    If model.IsValid = False Then
        MsgBox "fill in the blanks"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim explorer As InternetExplorer
    Set explorer = New InternetExplorer
    explorer.Visible = True
    
    GetToLogin explorer
    
    Dim page As HTMLDocument
    Set page = explorer.document
    
    InputPassword page
    ClickLogin page
    
    HoldUp explorer
    
    GetToTimeOff explorer
    Set page = explorer.document
    
    FillOutForm page, model
    SubmitRequest page
    
    HoldUp explorer
    'TODO: check to make sure submission was successful
    explorer.Quit
End Sub
```

My plan for checking to make sure the submission is successful is to check the `explorer.address` to make sure the page goes to the confirmation page, but I won't be able to know what that web address is until I actually submit for time off.

`FormModel` is an object that encapsulates all of the relevant information from [the sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mnXQ.png).  Here's what the code looks like:

```
Public Property Get FirstName() As String
    FirstName = Sheet1.Range("FirstName").Value
End Property
Public Property Get LastName() As String
    LastName = Sheet1.Range("LastName").Value
End Property
Public Property Get Department() As String
    Department = Sheet1.Range("Department").Value
End Property
Public Property Get Location() As String
    Location = Sheet1.Range("Location").Value
End Property
Public Property Get Email() As String
    Email = Sheet1.Range("Email").Value
End Property
Public Property Get ManagersEmail() As String
    ManagersEmail = Sheet1.Range("ManagersEmail").Value
End Property
Public Property Get VacationHours() As String
    VacationHours = Sheet1.Range("PTO").Value
End Property
Public Property Get UnpaidHours() As String
    UnpaidHours = Sheet1.Range("UnpaidHours").Value
End Property
Public Property Get Dates() As String
    Dates = Sheet1.Range("Dates").Value
End Property
Public Property Get Comments() As String
    Comments = Sheet1.Range("Comments").Value
End Property

Public Property Get IsValid() As Boolean
    'if any fields are empty besides comments (comments are not required by the timeoff webpage), returns false
    IsValid = Not ((FirstName = vbNullString) Or (LastName = vbNullString) Or _
                    (Department = vbNullString) Or (Location = vbNullString) Or _
                    (Email = vbNullString) Or (ManagersEmail = vbNullString) Or _
                    (VacationHours = vbNullString) Or (UnpaidHours = vbNullString) Or _
                    (Dates = vbNullString))
End Property
```

And here are all the various helper procedures found in main:

```
Private Sub GetToLogin(ByVal explorer As InternetExplorer)
    explorer.navigate "https://example.com/loginpage"
    HoldUp explorer
End Sub

Private Sub InputPassword(ByVal page As HTMLDocument)
    Dim passwordBox As IHTMLElement
    Set passwordBox = page.getElementById("pass")
    
    passwordBox.Value = "supersecrettotallyrealpassword"
End Sub

Private Sub ClickLogin(ByVal page As HTMLDocument)
    Dim submitButton As IHTMLElement
    'this submit button doesn't have an id for some reason
    Set submitButton = page.getElementsByName("submit").Item(0)
    
    submitButton.Click
End Sub

Private Sub GetToTimeOff(ByVal explorer As InternetExplorer)
    explorer.navigate "https://example.com/relevantform"
    HoldUp explorer
End Sub

Private Sub HoldUp(ByVal explorer As InternetExplorer)
    Do While explorer.Busy Or explorer.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub FillOutForm(ByVal page As HTMLDocument, ByVal model As FormModel)
    InputName page, model
    InputDepartment page, model
    InputLocation page, model
    InputEmail page, model
    InputManagerEmail page, model
    InputPTO page, model
    InputUnpaidHours page, model
    InputDates page, model
    InputComments page, model
End Sub

Private Sub SubmitRequest(ByVal page As HTMLDocument)
    Dim submitButton As IHTMLElement
    Set submitButton = page.getElementById("vac_request_submit")
    
    submitButton.Click
End Sub

Private Sub InputName(ByVal page As HTMLDocument, ByVal model As FormModel)
    Dim firstNameBox As IHTMLElement
    Set firstNameBox = page.getElementById("fname")
    Dim lastNameBox As IHTMLElement
    Set lastNameBox = page.getElementById("lname")
    
    firstNameBox.Value = model.FirstName
    lastNameBox.Value = model.LastName
End Sub
Private Sub InputDepartment(ByVal page As HTMLDocument, ByVal model As FormModel)
    Dim departmentBox As IHTMLElement
    Set departmentBox = page.getElementById("department")
    
    departmentBox.Value = model.Department
End Sub
Private Sub InputLocation(ByVal page As HTMLDocument, ByVal model As FormModel)
    Dim locationBox As IHTMLElement
    Set locationBox = page.getElementById("location")
    
    locationBox.Value = model.Location
End Sub
Private Sub InputEmail(ByVal page As HTMLDocument, ByVal model As FormModel)
    Dim emailBox As IHTMLElement
    Set emailBox = page.getElementById("email")
    
    emailBox.Value = model.Email
End Sub
Private Sub InputManagerEmail(ByVal page As HTMLDocument, ByVal model As FormModel)
    Dim managerBox As IHTMLElement
    Set managerBox = page.getElementById("man_email")
    
    managerBox.Value = model.ManagersEmail
End Sub
Private Sub InputPTO(ByVal page As HTMLDocument, ByVal model As FormModel)
    Dim PTOBox As IHTMLElement
    Set PTOBox = page.getElementById("request_vac")
    
    PTOBox.Value = model.VacationHours
End Sub
Private Sub InputUnpaidHours(ByVal page As HTMLDocument, ByVal model As FormModel)
    Dim unpaidBox As IHTMLElement
    Set unpaidBox = page.getElementById("request_unpaid")
    
    unpaidBox.Value = model.UnpaidHours
End Sub
Private Sub InputDates(ByVal page As HTMLDocument, ByVal model As FormModel)
    Dim datesBox As IHTMLElement
    Set datesBox = page.getElementById("off_time")
    
    datesBox.Value = model.Dates
End Sub
Private Sub InputComments(ByVal page As HTMLDocument, ByVal model As FormModel)
    Dim commentsBox As IHTMLElement
    Set commentsBox = page.getElementById("comments")
    
    commentsBox.Value = model.Comments
End Sub
```

I think the various InputX procedures are the things I'm least happy with, but I'm not exactly sure what I could do to make it better.

Comment: You are aware, that scraping is the worst method to do web-automation? Best is an API (e.g. Rest) to make request as Websites are designed for human readers, APIs for machines. E.g a website gets a redesign (usually no notification), humans are happy as it is more beautiful, machine is sad  as can't get the data till programmer tells how-to. If API changes,you get notified, old version is availble some time together with new one (time to adapt code)- If no APi availble you can at least skip those simulated user action (click nutton) and rebuild resulting the form submit request instead

Comment: Explorer HoldUp function relies on `explorer.Busy Or explorer.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE` what is not reliable as e-g  iframes create `READYSTATE_COMPLETE` if loaded and you may need to wait for js code executed. To make that more reliable you may check if a specific HTMLElement is availible in DOM and if not return to readystate loop.  More improvement can be done by using explorers events (WithEvents) and catch the Document_Completed event (needs check for frames) and then check DOM for `readystate: complete` then code can start scraping. I'll add that as an answer, maybe next week.

Comment: I actually didn't know about any of that stuff, I'm still pretty new to coding in general.  I look forward to your answer!

Comment: If you are on company private network and internally built webpage, API may not be available. In this case, try to talk to your IT to see if they can come up with API endpoints for your needs. That is truly the most efficient and correct way to do it for now. In short, API allows you to `GET` data from and `POST` data to a website. It does not use username-password login method, but uses API-key authentication which shall be provided uniquely for each user.